# Highcharts - From Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, highcharts

I have some problems with Highcharts and servlet/jsp.

I'm not very familiar with AJAX and JQUERY.

I would like to display in a jsp page 2 real-time line series with the relevant data (x,y) loaded from a database through a java servlet.

This is the code inside my jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var seriesOptions = [];
    $.getJSON('Grafico', function(data) {

        // Populate series
        for (i = 0; i < data.DeltaRealTime.length; i++){
            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: data.DeltaRealTime[i].name,
                data: [data.DeltaRealTime[i].key, parseFloat(data.DeltaRealTime[i].value)]
            };
        }

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,

                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        setInterval(function() {

                            $.getJSON('Grafico', function(data) {
                                // Populate series
                                for (i = 0; i < data.DeltaRealTime.length; i++){
                                    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                                    chart.series[i].addPoint([data.DeltaRealTime[i].key, parseFloat(data.DeltaRealTime[i].value)]);
                                }
                            });
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "Valori Delta"
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Campione'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: '{value:.1f}'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Delta(f)'
                },
            },
            series: seriesOptions
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the "Grafico" servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        Seriale seriale = (Seriale)session.getAttribute("seriale");

        if(seriale == null)
            System.out.println("SERIALE=NULL");
        else {
            if(seriale.getSeriale().isOpen())
                System.out.println("SERIALE APERTA");

            System.out.println("ID SESSIONE DATI="+seriale.getSessioneDati().getId());
        }


        if(seriale != null && seriale.getSeriale().isOpen()) {

            System.out.println("INIZIO A LEGGERE I DATI DAL DB");

            Db db = new Db();
            db.apriConnessione();

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM MisuraRiposo ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
            PreparedStatement ps = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            Map<String, String> data1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
            Map<String, String> data2 = new HashMap<String,String>();

            if(rs.next()) {
                data1.put("name", "f1");
                data1.put("key", rs.getString("campione"));
                data1.put("value", rs.getString("f1"));
                data2.put("name", "f2");
                data2.put("key", rs.getString("campione"));
                data2.put("value", rs.getString("f2"));
            }

            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            db.chiudiConnessione();

            JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(data1);
            JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(data2);
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            array.put(json1);
            array.put(json2);
            JSONObject finalObject = new JSONObject();
            finalObject.put("DeltaRealTime", array);

            out.write(finalObject.toString());
        }

    }
    catch(JSONException jse) {
        jse.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("Fine servlet grafico");
    }

}
```

The problem is that I can't obtain the desired behaviour. I only obtain disconnected points.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: $.getJSON Description: `Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.` Yet in your servlet you have a doPost method rather than doGet. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Sorry to have omitted this information but my doGet method is simply a call to the doPost method: protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  
  doPost(request, response);
  
 }.

Comment: The one thing I would suggest is JS is hard to read when everything is defined as `$(function (){` and nothing is a named function like `function x(){` If you had made the function that calls the Ajax and the success handler func named functions you could call them at different points rather than having to copy and paste their code twice. That might also make it easier to tell what's going on and thus fix the problem. Just a thought.

Comment: I add that the "finalObject.toString()" method of the doPost method prints out a string like this: {"DeltaRealTime":[{"name":"f1","value":"20099506.5","key":"362"},{"name":"f2","value":"20055460.1","key":"362"}]} where (362,20099506.5) are (x,y) values of f1 serie and (362,20055460.1) are (x,y) values of f2 serie

Comment: So now json is returned, if yes you need to parse your json to have x/y values instead of value/key. Morever all values should be numbers, but date needs to be timestamp (time in miliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It seems a JQUERY issue on Internet Explorer.

```
$.getJSON('Grafico', function(data) { ... }
```

doesn't work in IE11.

I changed it with

```
$.ajax({
                        type: $('#form1').attr('method'),
                        url: "Grafico",
                        cache:false,
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(data){
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.DeltaRealTime.length; i++){
                                chart1.series[i].addPoint([parseInt(data.DeltaRealTime[i].key),parseFloat(data.DeltaRealTime[i].value)]);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

and all works very well.